# How to prevent Mac OS X creating .DS_Store files on non Mac (HFS) Volumes?

Tags: windows, macos, partitioning

Is there a way to prevent Mac OS X creating .DS_Store and other hidden meta-files on foreign volumes like NTFS and FAT?
I share an NTFS partition with data like Thunderird & Firefox's profiles and apache's DocumentRoot, between Mac OS X and Windows, which is very handy.
I don't mind if Mac OS X is not capable of indexing or otherwise doing the neat things those metafiles are for.

Note: It's not shared over a network, both operating systems and the shared partition coexist on the same disk, on the same machine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are sharing the NTFS partition over a network, using SMB or some such, you can turn it off.

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

Apple tech bulletin "[How to prevent .DS_Store file creation over network connections](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1629)".  I have not verified that this still works with Snow Leopard.

Comment: I'm not sure that works unless they actually are on a network drive.

Comment: @alex  I think you're right.  The OP hasn't said how he is sharing the NTFS partition.  I'll edit my answer, but it may be flat out wrong.

Comment: Nope, not over the network. One disk only, Mac OS in one partition, Windows on the other, and a NTFS partition for shared files.

Comment: PS: Sorry, what does OP stand for? I know it refers to me, but don't know the meaning.

Comment: @Richard Hoskins: your answer refers to preventing the creation of .DS_Store files over the network. There's no way of stopping this if it's on the same drive. @sudo petrutza: OP means **Original Poster** (had no idea either)

Answer (score 6):

I use this I set it up once when I got annoyed with the same problem. This method make the system do it all automatically.

1. Create a script called Remove_Hidden_Files.sh by opening terminal and for example cd ~/Documents and type touch Remove_Hidden_Files.sh
2. Using vi create the script. In Terminal type `vi Remove_Hidden_Files.sh`
3. Press "I" to get in to insert mode and type the following (Hint to get # press alt and 3)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Removing the hidden files from my drive using the find command. Change xxx to the name of your external volume or path you wish to run the command on.
   # the -mount will stop the find command going to other volumes other than specified.

   find -x /Volumes/(xxx) -mount -name '.DS_Store' | xargs rm -rf
   find -x /Volumes/(xxx) -mount -name '.Spotlight-V100' | xargs rm -rf
   find -x /Volumes/(xxx) -mount -name '.Trashes' | xargs rm -rf
   find -x /Volumes/(xxx) -mount -name '._.Trashes' | xargs rm -rf
   find -x /Volumes/(xxx) -mount -name '.fseventsd' | xargs rm -rf
   ```
4. Press escape to get out of insert mode and hold shift and press `:`
5. Type `wq!` and then press enter
6. Make the script executable `chmod 775 ~/Documents/Remove_Hidden_Files.sh`
7. Test this out to make sure it works. You can easily do this by opening terminal and type cd /Volumes/(xxx) press enter and then ls -la to list all the files and you should see a .DS_Store if not navigate with the finder to the volume and then repeat the command and you should see one there.
8. Open another terminal by pressing command key and N
9. Type `cd ~/Documents`
10. Type `sh Remove_Hidden_Files.sh`
11. Go to the other terminal window and check the .DS_Store files are removed.
12. Create a launch daemon. This means to run automatically so you don't have to do anything.

    Best way is to download lingon
13. Create a daemon for you user account and call it com.remove_hidden_files.Launchd
14. In the command box type `sh ~/Documents/Remove_Hidden_Files.sh`
15. You can either type in the path or browse to it /Volumes/(xxx)
16. Reboot the machine and try it out

Note if you rename your external drive, use a different named drive or path you will need to change the script.

Comment: I like how this answer became a vim tutorial. Haha

Comment: You can add Mac logout scripts without paying for third party apps by using `sudo defaults...` http://seeskill.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/mac-os-x-login-and-logout-scripts-demystified/

Comment: So this cleaning will happen when? when you log in?

Answer (score 5):

I use BlueHarvest for this purpose:

https://zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/

Works across all volumes and not just network shares as per Apple's solution.

Comment: FYI, BlueHarvest is a Mac program that costs $15 US for 3 computers (more $ for more computers), and has a "30 day free trial"

Comment: The BlueHarvest web site linked above is unresponsive at the moment, which would appear to mean that support is unavailable. However the app is in the App Store.

Comment: I've updated the URL.