# Mac friendly file sharing from VirtualBox

Tags: linux, mac, virtualbox

I have set up Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu into a VirtualBox instance on my PC, I enabled Samba and I'm connecting to it via the home network from my Mac. All is fine except that I have some issues deleting some files from inside applications e.g. in Sublime Text 2 when I right click a file in the browser and select delete nothing happens (same in my Git client). To be able to delete files I have to navigate to the folder in Finder (which leaves those nasty .DS_Store files scattered all around) or issue the delete command from the terminal (inconvenient). If you're asking why I'm using VirtualBox for Rails instead of doing the development directly on the Mac it's because the ease of portability.

So my question is: are there any network sharing options which I could use to make the Linux instance play nicer with my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ready to play with the terminal, you might want to use `rsync` with ssh on the linux guest to sync your files.  I should be called with something like `rsync --delete ~/Documents/RailsSite/ ubuntu:/var/www/RailsSite/  But I understand you don't want to use to much of the cli.

If it's only the `.DS_Store` files that bothers you when using the Finder to delete files, you might want to check that [other Question](https://superuser.com/questions/212896/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-a-mac-from-creating-dot-underscore-files) that has a nice tool, [Blue Harvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/), to disable creating those files on network drives.

But the deletion issue you're seeing are probably related to incorrect permissions on your shared folder.  You might want to check if you can relax those a bit, maybe by putting the shared root directory and all sub directories in 777 mode (if it's not making a security issue, I mean if your gest Ubuntu is not open to the world).  This could be as easy as a one time command `chmod -R 777 /home/user/RailsSite/`