# How can I permanently delete hidden files/folders on Mac USB drive?

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive

I am aware that you can delete [Mac OS X hidden files/folders](http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/invisibles.html) (such as `/.Spotlight-V100` or `.DS_Store`) on a USB drive using various scripts. But then the hidden files/folders get added again before you eject it.

Is there any way to prevent this, and if so - how?

Comment: Are you talking about specific files?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg the ones that OS X adds automatically. http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/invisibles.html. all of them.

Comment: It might be helpful if you [put the names of the hidden files in your question](http://superuser.com/posts/429091/edit). That way people will quickly know what you mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Mac OS X creating .DS_Store files on non Mac (HFS) Volumes?](http://superuser.com/questions/47918/how-to-prevent-mac-os-x-creating-ds-store-files-on-non-mac-hfs-volumes)

Comment: some help here too [How disable mac snow leopard creating .Spotlight-V100 and .Trash folders in USB Flash Drivers?](http://superuser.com/questions/89556/how-disable-mac-snow-leopard-creating-spotlight-v100-and-trash-folders-in-usb)

Comment: Duplicate of: [How disable creating .Spotlight-V100 and .Trash folders on external drive?](http://superuser.com/q/89556/87805)

Answer (score 3):

To prevent /.Spotlight files you must prevent Spotlight fron indexing external drives.

To do this for a specific drive add a file called **.metadata_never_index** to the root directory of the removable drive.

You can also completely prevent spotlight indexing but I figured that was not what you were looking for.

To prevent .DS_Store files from being created:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

More Info [Here (And More files that you can prevent)](http://hostilefork.com/2009/12/02/trashes-fseventsd-and-spotlight-v100/) and [Here](http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/03/how-to-prevent-ds_store-file-creation/)