# Any programs for getting rid of .DS_Store files?

Tags: windows, macos, .ds-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent Mac OS X creating .DS_Store files on non Mac (HFS) Volumes?](https://superuser.com/questions/47918/how-to-prevent-mac-os-x-creating-ds-store-files-on-non-mac-hfs-volumes)

I dual boot between Mac and Windows. When I browse my Windows partition with Finder, it drops little `.DS_Store` turds all over the folders. They show up when I boot back into Windows. Right now I've got one on my Desktop, sigh.

Are there any (free) programs I can use to stop this from happening? I know, I know, there's a Finder setting to stop dropping `.DS_Store` files on network drives, but my local Windows partition is NOT a network drive.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it personally, but have had BlueHarvest recommended to me for this...

http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/

From the site:

> The easiest way to keep your disks and file servers clean of Mac
>   “dust”. BlueHarvest automatically removes DS_Store and ._ AppleDouble
>   files (resource forks) from your USB keys, SD cards and file servers,
>   etc. BlueHarvest removes these items as they’re created so you’ll
>   always be “dust” free.