# What is .DS_Store file in windows

Tags: windows-7, .ds-store

I found a file with `.DS_Store` extension in one of my drives. How did it get there?

My Operating System is Windows 7 64-bit and to the best of my knowledge I never accessed an Apple computer nor was accessed by one.

Comment: Chances are you had that drive plugged into an Apple computer or an Apple computer remotely accessed that drive.

Comment: No. There has been never any connection between my computer and apple computer or any Macintosh OS.

Comment: When you [googled it](https://www.google.ca/search?q=.DS_Store), and read the [first result (from Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store), what didn't you understand?

Comment: In Wikipedia I found out that this file is related to Mac OS. Since There is Windows Operating System in my machine I got wondered!

Comment: That same wonder has brought me here, thank you for asking this question!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

That file is a proprietary Mac/OSX system file that holds attributes/meta-data about the folder it resides in.

These often appear in file shares that are accessed over the network by a Mac user; but that's not the only way you can get them.  You may have gotten it in an archive (ie: a Zip file perhaps) you picked up someplace, which was originally created on a Mac.

I run into these all the time in archives we get from our graphic designers.

You're safe to just delete it.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store

For additional information on preventing them, perhaps check out these SU questions and answers (and others like them):

- [How to prevent Mac OS X creating .DS_Store files on non Mac (HFS) Volumes?](https://superuser.com/questions/47918/how-to-prevent-mac-os-x-creating-ds-store-files-on-non-mac-hfs-volumes)
- [Any programs for getting rid of .DS_Store files?](https://superuser.com/questions/484273/any-programs-for-getting-rid-of-ds-store-files?lq=1)

Comment: Thanx my friend. The problem is that there' no relation between my computer and Mac/OSX and also there's no Zip or compressed file in root of my Drive That I extract it.

Comment: That's where they come from, but if you don't know how it got there and you swear nothing has ever been done to put it there, then we can't tell you where you picked it up from, and we probably can't convince you it's harmless.  If you are really worried it's an infection or something, then format and reinstall Windows. :)

Comment: If you are using `git` (or `git for Windows`) you can add `.DS_Store` to the `.gitignore` file so it won't get checked in.